# generate random words from the list of words in c programming

Tags: c, random, cpu-word, generator

hey, i wanna ask if i have a list of words let say 'tiger, lion, elephant, zebra, horse, camel, deer, crocodile, rabbit, cat'
haw can i generate 5 words out of the list randomly in c programming?
for example:

tiger, zebra, cat, deer, horse

or

crocodile, rabbit, camel, zebra, elephant

ect

thank you in advance :D

**Edit**:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10 

int main () 
{ 

char arr2[SIZE][20] = { "tiger", "lion", "elephant", "zebra", "horse", "camel", "deer", "crocodile", "rabbit", "cat" }; 

int x = 0; 
srand(time(NULL));

while (x < SIZE - 5) 
{ 
    arr2 [x][20] = rand (); 
    printf ("%s\n", arr2[x]); 
    x++; 
}

system ("pause"); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: What line `arr2 [x][20] = rand ();` supposes to do?

Comment: i dunno... i just tried it myself :( my teacher don't even teach me bout generating random words and i just find by myself through the net.

Comment: What do you think this line does? Or what do you want it to do? You didn't just typed some random garbage, right?

Answer (score 3):

Put the words into an array. Generate 5 (or whatever) pseudo-random numbers in the right range (0..array_size-1). Use those numbers to pick words from the array.

Comment: i'm blur... i dont get it. :( sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. You already have an array which holds the elements(names of the animals)
2. You can access each element by an index, say `k` and you can access the array elements  like this `arr2[k]`.
3. Now you need to get a random number assigned to k everytime. This can be done by using the standard library's `rand` function which you have probably called but in a wrong way
4. Once you have printed out a value you need to keep track of it, so use a integer array `check[SIZE] = {0,}`and before printing `arr2[k]`, check if `check[k]==0` and then print the value. After printing set `arr2[k]=1`.

Once you are done with this much please paste your code. Hope you will understand the logic to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For illustrative purposes, this is C# but I'm sure you can convert to C, fairly easily:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] words =     
                { "tiger", "lion", "elephant", "zebra", "horse", 
                  "camel", "deer", "crocodile", "rabbit", "cat"  };

        string randomWords = RandomWords.GenerateRandomWordString(5, words); 
    }


public static class RandomWords
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    public static string GenerateRandomWordString(int numWords, string[] words)
    {
        int maxlen = words.Length;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
        {
            // Note: in .NET, Random.Next(0, max) returns 
            // a value in range zero to max - 1
            sb.Append(words[_random.Next(0, maxlen)]);
            sb.Append(" ");
        }

        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!! but seriously, i don't have any idea how to convert it to c... oh... i'm really a stupid =.="

Comment: @falcon: this can be healed by learning, listening and such things, really

Comment: i have this

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main ()
{
   char arr2[SIZE][20] =       
                { "tiger", "lion", "elephant", "zebra", "horse",  
                  "camel", "deer", "crocodile", "rabbit", "cat"  };
    int x = 0;
 srand(time(NULL));
 while (x < SIZE - 5) 
 {
   arr2 [x][20] = rand ();
      printf ("%s\n", arr2[x]);
   x++;
 }


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

it's really sucks izit?

Comment: hey, i already did it myself!! yes. my code just now was totally garbage and now i already make a new one and it's work!!  but i dunno if it's really work corrrectly. for now, as i run it, it can generate five random word. btw, thanks for your help :D